# Phone Number Hint is not returning any phone number

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I am using the latest updated for requesting the phone number as hint.

```
GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest getPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest = GetPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest.builder().build();

        Identity.getSignInClient(this)
                .getPhoneNumberHintIntent(getPhoneNumberHintIntentRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(pendingIntent -> {
                    IntentSenderRequest intentSenderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(pendingIntent.getIntentSender()).build();
                    hintStartActivityForResult.launch(intentSenderRequest);
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Log.e("exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                });
```

**But it return the exception 16: No phone number is found on this device. But the previous version of phone number hint was working on the same device.**

```
 private final ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> hintStartActivityForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        if (data != null) {
                            try {
                                String phoneNumber = Identity.getSignInClient(context).getPhoneNumberFromIntent(result.getData());
                            } catch (ApiException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: HI, I am also facing similar issue. Did you find anything on this ?

Comment: Not Yet currently we are going with previous version. Hopping to google will resolve this issue soon.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue:
Samsung device SM-G988B/DS
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0
South African SIM